# Associating an `AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent` with the remote address in the presence of XFF headers

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-security, x-forwarded-for

So I wrote this ...

```
@Component
class AuthenticationFailureListener : ApplicationListener<AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent>{

    private val bruteForceProtection : BruteForceProtection

    @Inject
    constructor(bruteForceProtection: BruteForceProtection){
        this.bruteForceProtection = bruteForceProtection
    }

    override fun onApplicationEvent(event: AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent) {
        val webDetails = event.authentication.details as WebAuthenticationDetails
        val remoteAddress = webDetails.remoteAddress

        bruteForceProtection.recordFailedAttempt(remoteAddress)
    }
}
```

Then realised I have no idea if Spring accounts for `X-Forwarded-For` headers when setting the remote address in the security context.

Does it?

Or how would I associate the `AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent` with the remote address it originated from?

Comment: Are you using Tomcat?

Comment: @caco3 the embedded one that comes with Spring Boot, yes.

Answer (score 2):

From [Spring Security#15.4 Proxy Server Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-proxy-server):

> When using a proxy server it is important to ensure that you have configured your application properly. For example, many applications will have a load balancer that responds to request for `https://example.com/` by forwarding the request to an application server at `https://192.168.1:8080` Without proper configuration, the application server will not know that the load balancer exists and treat the request as though `https://192.168.1:8080` was requested by the client.
>
> To fix this you can use RFC 7239 to specify that a load balancer is being used. To make the application aware of this, you need to either **configure your application server aware of the `X-Forwarded` headers**. For example Tomcat uses the `RemoteIpValve` and Jetty uses `ForwardedRequestCustomizer`. Alternatively, **Spring 4.3+ users can leverage `ForwardedHeaderFilter`.**

Neither Spring framework nor Spring Security itself do anything special about `X-Forwarded*` headers.

So our options to apply such information are:

- exposing the [`ForwardedHeaderFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/ForwardedHeaderFilter.html)
- configuring the server

Unfortunately **`ForwardedHeaderFilter` does not [inspect `X-Forwarded-For` header](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/e0654a5b3dcf55a7840cd29d25c55854a071202c/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/filter/ForwardedHeaderFilter.java#L71)** as of `5.1.7.RELEASE`.

So the option left is to configure server.

Since you're using tomcat you can supply a `server.tomcat.remote-ip-header` property to take the header into account.

*See also [`ServerProperties`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.java)*

**application.yml**:

```
server:
  tomcat:
    remote-ip-header: X-Forwarded-For
```

then [`getRemoteAddr`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteAddr()) will return the ip address present in `X-Forwarded-For` header which is used by [`WebAuthenticationDetails`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/e7f93f221d4b828d336627f5147a3edd02a8c28d/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/WebAuthenticationDetails.java#L50) itself

**`WebAuthenticationDetails.java`**

```java
public WebAuthenticationDetails(HttpServletRequest request) {
    this.remoteAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();

    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    this.sessionId = (session != null) ? session.getId() : null;
}
```

Here is a test a simple test:

**`IpController.kt`**:

```
@RestController
class IpController {
    @GetMapping("/ip")
    fun getIp(request: HttpServletRequest) = mapOf("ip" to request.remoteAddr)
}
```

**`IpControllerTest.kt`**

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = ["server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=X-Forwarded-For"],
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class IpControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var testRestTemplate: TestRestTemplate

    @Test
    fun `uses ip from x-forwarded-for`() {
        val httpHeaders = HttpHeaders()
        httpHeaders["X-Forwarded-For"] = "8.8.8.8"
        val httpEntity = HttpEntity<Any>(httpHeaders)
        val map = testRestTemplate.exchange<Map<String, *>>("/ip", HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity)
                .body!!
        assertEquals("8.8.8.8", map["ip"])
    }
}
```