# How do I change the request IP for testing?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, kotlin

So as a follow-up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56133593/associating-an-authenticationfailurebadcredentialsevent-with-the-remote-addres), I am writing a couple of sanity tests to verify Spring Boot's `server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=X-Forwarded-For` is working as intended...

```
@RestController
class RemoteAddressTesterController {
    @GetMapping("/remoteAddr")
    fun getRemoteAddress(request: HttpServletRequest):String = request.remoteAddr
}
```

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest(
    properties = ["server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=X-Forwarded-For"],
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
)
class RemoteAddressProviderIT{

    private val NON_LOCAL_IP_1 = "212.13.43.12"
    private val NON_LOCAL_IP_2 = "12.13.24.34"
    private val LOCAL_HOST = "127.0.0.1"

    @Inject
    lateinit var rest:TestRestTemplate

    private lateinit var headers:HttpHeaders

    @Before
    fun setup(){
        headers = HttpHeaders()
    }
```

works:

```
    @Test
    fun withoutXFF_localhost() {
        val request = HttpEntity<Any>(headers)



        val remoteAddress = rest.exchange("/remoteAddr", HttpMethod.GET,request,String::class.java).body!!



        assertThat(remoteAddress).isEqualTo(LOCAL_HOST)
    }
```

this works too:

```
    @Test
    fun XFF_clientWithProxy() {
        headers["X-Forwarded-For"] = "$NON_LOCAL_IP_2,$NON_LOCAL_IP_1"
        val request = HttpEntity<Any>(headers)



        val remoteAddress = rest.exchange("/remoteAddr", HttpMethod.GET,request,String::class.java).body!!



        assertThat(remoteAddress).isEqualTo(NON_LOCAL_IP_1)
    }
```

This, however ...

```
    @Test
    fun withoutXFF_remoteOrigin(){
        headers.origin = NON_LOCAL_IP_1
        headers.host = InetSocketAddress(NON_LOCAL_IP_1,8080)
        val request = HttpEntity<Any>(headers)



        val remoteAddress = rest.exchange("/remoteAddr", HttpMethod.GET,request,String::class.java).body!!



        assertThat(remoteAddress).isEqualTo(NON_LOCAL_IP_1)
    }
```

gives me an

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :"212.13.43.12"
Actual   :"127.0.0.1"
```

My expectation, here, is that the IP is taken from the IP header, not the HTTP headers. Can I somehow change that IP to verify?

Comment: according to the docs, Origin is only set for CORS or POST https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin