# X-Forwarded-Proto et al. support in JHipster with Undertow

Tags: java, load-balancing, jhipster, undertow

JHipster 5.8.2 based Java application here

We've been encountering issue when our app is hosted under an OpenShift Load Balancer in a private cloud. As app internally listens insecure HTTP and the external endpoint is `https`, our internal SSO library constructed erroneous "http"-based ReturnURL for the SAML endpoint, which led to errors in processing SSO redirects in browser.

We had to switch to Tomcat (JHipster uses Undertow since 3.7.0, it seems (https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/4054)), and had to specify `server.tomcat.remote-ip-header` and `server.tomcat.protocol-header` in order to fix this (specifying these properties enables `RemoteIpValve` in Tomcat, which does the trick)

But I couldn't google out how to achieve this with Undertow 1.4? Are there any docs on how to configure/troubleshoot this?

I presume, that using Undertow over Tomcat should have some advantages, so I would like to give it another try.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can do it on Spring level. Check out [`ForwardedHeaderFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/ForwardedHeaderFilter.html). Probably you will need to adapt it to make it consider `X-Forwarded-For` header. [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56133593/associating-an-authenticationfailurebadcredentialsevent-with-the-remote-addres)

Comment: Possibly try setting `server.use-forward-headers: true` in your `application.yml` config  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-web-servers.html#howto-use-tomcat-behind-a-proxy-server